# How to center a PictureBox inside a ScrollableControl and then autoscroll on resize

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls, scroll

Having a bit of trouble trying to center the view on the center of the element inside a ScrollableControl.

I have no problems centering the control inside the ScrollableControl, however whenever I try to set AutoScrollPosition, the element inside the scroll container docks to the bottom right corner of the innermost container of the ScrollableControl.

Here is the code that I am using (and I am pretty sure the math is correct) :

```
MyBase.AutoScrollPosition = New System.Drawing.Point(Canvas1.Left - ((MyBase.Width - Canvas1.Size.Width) / 2), Canvas1.Top - ((MyBase.Height - Canvas1.Size.Height) / 2))
```

The type of project is actually a UserControl, not a Class, so this is not an "inherited" ScrollableControl per se.  It is a UserControl type.

What I find most bizzare, is there doesn't appear to be a ScrollToX, only ScrollControlIntoView, and such, which do not do what I wish.

Basically, the end result, is the center of the Viewable area must be the center of the Control contained inside the Scrollable virtual area.  I have the Control centered as such, so this is really just a matter of scrolling it into view so the X,Y of the dead center of the inner control, is in the dead center of the viewable area.

Current code for the entire class

### Board.vb

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Board

    Private _init As Boolean = False

    Private _keys As KeyEventArgs = Nothing

    ''' <summary>
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <filterpriority>3</filterpriority>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    <Browsable(False), EditorBrowsable(False)> _
    Shadows Property BackgroundImage As Image
        Get
            Return MyBase.BackgroundImage
        End Get
        Set(value As Image)
            MyBase.BackgroundImage = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <Browsable(False), EditorBrowsable(False)> _
    Shadows Property AutoScroll As Boolean
        Get
            Return MyBase.AutoScroll
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            MyBase.AutoScroll = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <Browsable(False), EditorBrowsable(False)> _
    Shadows Property AutoScrollMinSize As System.Drawing.Size
        Get
            Return MyBase.AutoScrollMinSize
        End Get
        Set(value As System.Drawing.Size)
            MyBase.AutoScrollMinSize = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Checkerboard As Boolean
        Get
            Return Canvas1.CheckeredBackground
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            Canvas1.CheckeredBackground = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Shadows Property BorderStyle As Windows.Forms.BorderStyle
        Get
            Return Canvas1.BorderStyle
        End Get
        Set(value As Windows.Forms.BorderStyle)
            Canvas1.BorderStyle = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub Canvas1_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Canvas1.MouseEnter
        Me.Focus()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Add(ByVal Image As System.Drawing.Image)
        Dim l As New Layer("Layer " & Canvas1.Layers.Count + 1)
        l.Graphics.Add(New Graphic(Image, New Point(10, 10)))
        Canvas1.Layers.Add(l)
    End Sub

    Public Property CanvasSize() As System.Drawing.Size
        Get
            Return Canvas1.Size
        End Get
        Set(value As System.Drawing.Size)
            Canvas1.Size = value
            Me.CenterCanvas()
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property BoardSize() As System.Drawing.Size
        Get
            Return Me.AutoScrollMinSize
        End Get
        Set(value As System.Drawing.Size)
            Me.AutoScrollMinSize = value
            Me.CenterCanvas()
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Function Remove(ByVal Index As Integer) As Boolean
        Try
            Canvas1.Layers.RemoveAt(Index)
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Sub RefreshCanvas()
        Canvas1.Invalidate()
    End Sub

    Public Sub CenterCanvas()
        Canvas1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point((MyBase.DisplayRectangle.Width - Canvas1.Size.Width) / 2, (MyBase.DisplayRectangle.Height - Canvas1.Size.Height) / 2)


        'Debug.Print(Canvas1.Top & ", " & Canvas1.Left)

        '        Dim y As Integer = (Me.Height - Canvas1.Height) / 2
        '        Dim x As Integer = (Me.Width - Canvas1.Width) / 2
        '        x = Canvas1.Left - x
        '        y = Canvas1.Top - y


        '        Me.AutoScrollPosition = New System.Drawing.Point(x, y)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.

        InitializeComponent()
        _init = True
        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Me.CenterCanvas()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Board_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        _keys = e
    End Sub

    Private Sub Board_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
        _keys = Nothing
    End Sub

    Private Sub Board_MouseWheel(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseWheel
        Dim l As Layer

        l = Canvas1.SelectedLayer
        If IsNothing(l) = False Then
            Debug.Print("Wheels")
        End If

        Dim MW As HandledMouseEventArgs = e
        MW.Handled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Board_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
        '       If _init Then
        ' Dim x As Integer = Canvas1.Left - ((MyBase.Width - Canvas1.Size.Width) / 2)
        'Dim y As Integer = Canvas1.Top - ((MyBase.Height - Canvas1.Size.Height) / 2)
        '           MyBase.AutoScrollPosition = New System.Drawing.Point(Canvas1.Left - ((MyBase.Width - Canvas1.Size.Width) / 2), Canvas1.Top - ((MyBase.Height - Canvas1.Size.Height) / 2))
        'End If

        MyBase.AutoScrollPosition = New System.Drawing.Point( _
                Canvas1.Left - MyBase.AutoScrollPosition.X - ((MyBase.ClientSize.Width - Canvas1.Size.Width) \ 2), _
                Canvas1.Top - MyBase.AutoScrollPosition.Y - ((MyBase.ClientSize.Height - Canvas1.Size.Height) \ 2))
    End Sub

    Private Sub Board_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.SizeChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

### Board.Designer.vb

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class Board
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.UserControl

    'UserControl1 overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.Canvas1 = New Artisto.Canvas()
        CType(Me.Canvas1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'Canvas1
        '
        Me.Canvas1.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None
        Me.Canvas1.CheckeredBackground = True
        Me.Canvas1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
        Me.Canvas1.Name = "Canvas1"
        Me.Canvas1.SelectedLayer = Nothing
        Me.Canvas1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(619, 317)
        Me.Canvas1.TabIndex = 0
        Me.Canvas1.TabStop = False
        '
        'Board
        '
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Inherit
        Me.AutoScroll = True
        Me.AutoScrollMinSize = New System.Drawing.Size(4096, 2160)
        Me.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Canvas1)
        Me.DoubleBuffered = True
        Me.Name = "Board"
        Me.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(1266, 523)
        CType(Me.Canvas1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)

    End Sub
    Friend WithEvents Canvas1 As Artisto.Canvas

End Class
```

Comment: there seems to be something missing.  the refs to canvas1 (Artisto.Canvas()) all get flagged as errors (no such thing).  I suspect it is something imported from yesterdays code/post, but not sure

Comment: yes,  Canvas1 is a custom control. I can provide a zip with the full source if you wish

Comment: @Plutonix - any new thoughts on this ?